# Exporting data from HBase to MySql

Tags: mysql, hbase

I'm using HBase 0.92.1-cdh4.1.2. I have almost 100 tables in HBase [Size about 10GB]. I want to export all the data to MYSQL. I think sqoop isn't an viable option as it is used mostly to export from sql-nosql databases. And an other option would be exporting HBase data as flat files to local file system and dump the data to mysql using mysqlimport option !

Is there anyway, we can directly dump the data to mysql rather than exporting as flat files?

Comment: http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_3

Comment: @jeffmurphy Thanks. I'll try it out and let you know that !

Comment: @karunakar - Have you tried the Sqoop to export HBase to MySQL?